# Handing off control from Pygame to SDL2 causing CALayer exception

Tags: python, pygame, sdl, sdl-2

## Context

I work in cognitive science, so the context for this question is hard to convey. Long-story short, we have an extant library that heavily depends on PyGame; we need to use SDL2 for a specific, experimental task.

Our library extends a base class, `Exp` when we design experiments; it inits PyGame, has a simple and well-tested preparatory sequence, then passes control to the experimenter to complete a set of abstract methods which constitute the experiment.

**Goal:** At the handoff, kill PyGame and switch to SDL2.

**Problem:** The script below (**SDL2 script**) works when used outside of the `Exp` environment. But when it's changed just the little but (**Experiment Implementation**), two things happen:

1. the images that we're using SDL2 to load don't visibly draw (thought the SDL2 window does)
2. an exception is raised: `CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]`

**Current Suspect** Pygame and SDL2 are competing for namespace into two places, as evidenced from this terminal output at the program's launch:

```
objc[34300]: Class SDLTranslatorResponder is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/SDL2. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[34300]: Class SDLApplication is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/SDL2 and /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/sdlmain_osx.so. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Below are the working external script and the small modifications made to implement it within our Exp context. Finally, the complete error out put is at the bottom.

*Any advice on what this problem might be would be hugely appreciated!!!*

## SDL2 Script

```
import sdl2 
import sdl2.ext 
import numpy 
from PIL import Image 
import time 
import OpenGL.GL as gl
from scipy import misc
import os

stimDisplayRes = (1366,768) #pixel resolution of the stimDisplay    
imgs = []
img_path = "path/to/jpgs"
# this loop just grabs our images; works fine in both scripts
for x in range(1, 450):
    x = str(int(x * 2.5)).zfill(8)
    path = os.path.join(img_path, "{0}.jpg".format(x))
    imgs.append(numpy.array(Image.open(path)))


sdl2.SDL_Init(sdl2.SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
stimDisplay = sdl2.ext.Window("Experiment", size=stimDisplayRes,position=(0,0),flags=sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN| sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP |sdl2.SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | sdl2.SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC)
glContext = sdl2.SDL_GL_CreateContext(stimDisplay.window)
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
gl.glLoadIdentity()
gl.glOrtho(0, stimDisplayRes[0],stimDisplayRes[1], 0, 0, 1)
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
gl.glDisable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

sdl2.SDL_PumpEvents() # to show the windows

time.sleep(1)

def blitNumpy(numpyArray,xLoc,yLoc,xCentered=True,yCentered=True):
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND)
    gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    ID = gl.glGenTextures(1)
    gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID)
    gl.glTexEnvi(gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, gl.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, gl.GL_REPLACE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.GL_CLAMP)
    gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.GL_CLAMP)
    gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR)
    gl.glTexParameterf(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR)
    if len(numpyArray.shape)==3: #no alpha channel
        gl.glTexImage2D( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , gl.GL_RGBA , numpyArray.shape[1] , numpyArray.shape[0] , 0 , gl.GL_RGB , gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , numpyArray )
    elif len(numpyArray.shape)==4: #alpha channel
        gl.glTexImage2D( gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , gl.GL_RGBA , numpyArray.shape[1] , numpyArray.shape[0] , 0 , gl.GL_RGBA , gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , numpyArray )
    gl.glEnable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID)
    gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS)
    x1 = xLoc + 1.5 - 0.5
    x2 = xLoc + numpyArray.shape[1] - 0.0 + 0.5
    y1 = yLoc + 1.0 - 0.5
    y2 = yLoc + numpyArray.shape[0] - 0.5 + 0.5
    if xCentered:
        x1 = x1 - numpyArray.shape[1]/2.0
        x2 = x2 - numpyArray.shape[1]/2.0
    if yCentered:
        y1 = y1 - numpyArray.shape[0]/2.0
        y2 = y2 - numpyArray.shape[0]/2.0
    gl.glTexCoord2f( 0 , 0 )
    gl.glVertex2f( x1 , y1 )
    gl.glTexCoord2f( 1 , 0 )
    gl.glVertex2f( x2 , y1 )
    gl.glTexCoord2f( 1 , 1)
    gl.glVertex2f( x2 , y2 )
    gl.glTexCoord2f( 0 , 1 )
    gl.glVertex2f( x1, y2 )
    gl.glEnd()
    gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    gl.glDeleteTextures([ID])
    del ID
    gl.glDisable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    return None

# this is a little loop we're using to get our "frame rate" right; if this is made to work, I'm good from here
i = 0
j = 0
start = time.time()
while time.time()-start<10:
    time.sleep(.01) #pretend to do 5ms of other work per frame
    gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1)
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    blitNumpy(imgs[i],0,0,xCentered=False,yCentered=False)
    sdl2.SDL_GL_SwapWindow(stimDisplay.window)
    i+= 1
    if i == len(imgs):
        i=0
    j += 1

print j/(time.time()-start) # we just happen to need this metric
```

## Experiment Implementation

I'm not reposting the entire script; I literally change nothing but what's added here:

```
class Experiment(ExpLib.Exp):
    first_run = True  # 
    # bunch of methods that don't interact with either PyGame or SDL2—science stuff

    def trial(self, trial_factors, trial_num):
        if self.first_run:
            pygame.quit()
            self.first_run = False

        time.sleep(0.1)  # maybe unnecessary; just giving PyGame a chance to be fully shut down

        # this next call wraps the script above; the only difference is that 
        # blitNumpy becomes self.blitNumpy, and our FPS loop
        self.sdl_trial()  

        # the experiment's code will go here if I can get this to fly
```

## Console Output

> 2014-10-16 15:15:18.366 Python[34300:d07] An uncaught exception was
>   raised 2014-10-16 15:15:18.366 Python[34300:d07] CALayer position
>   contains NaN: [nan nan] 2014-10-16 15:15:18.366 Python[34300:d07] (   0
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fba325c
>   **exceptionPreprocess + 172   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff86dc3e75 objc_exception_throw + 43    2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff8fba310c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204     3   QuartzCore 
>   0x00007fff84cc425e _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 158   4
>   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff84cc41b7 -[CALayer
>   setPosition:] + 44    5   QuartzCore
>
>   0x00007fff84cc5e97 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 858     6   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8e5e837e -[_NSFullScreenTransitionOverlayWindow
>   positionLayers] + 1790    7   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8e5e8e61 -[_NSFullScreenTransitionOverlayWindow
>   startEnterFullScreenAnimationWithDuration:completionHandler:] + 55    8 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e5ead76
>   -[_NSFullScreenTransition _startFullScreenTransitionForCGWindow:targetFrame:duration:completionHandler:]
>   + 193     9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e5ecca6 __89-[_NSFullScreenTransition _performEnterFullScreenModeAnimating:activating:customWindows:]_block_invoke361
>   + 1430    10  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff84eafca2 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 47   11  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff84eafc2e _xpc_connection_call_reply + 36  12 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff869ab2ad
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff869b2f03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333  14 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fb0a679
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fac5954 **CFRunLoopRun
>   + 1636    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fac50b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309   17  HIToolbox
>
>   0x00007fff85ab9a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226    18  HIToolbox
>
>   0x00007fff85ab97b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479   19  HIToolbox
>
>   0x00007fff85ab95bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   65    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8dd293de
>   _DPSNextEvent + 1434  21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8dd28a2b -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122    22  SDL
>
>   0x000000011023243c SDL_SoftStretch + 7888     23  SDL
>
>   0x0000000110211efd SDL_PumpEvents + 38    24  SDL
>
>   0x00000001102120dd SDL_EventState + 200   25  SDL
>
>   0x00000001102303f6 SDL_JoystickEventState + 82    26  joystick.so
>
>   0x000000011040313d joy_autoinit + 42  27  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    28  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff9501f PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93     29  base.so
>
>   0x0000000110207c47 init + 279     30  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff921ef PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12338     31  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   32  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    33  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    34  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff239a7 PyMethod_New + 1200    35  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    36  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff92df5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416     37  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   38  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    39  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    40  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff239a7 PyMethod_New + 1200    41  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    42  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff5e6ce _PyObject_SlotCompare + 5565   43  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff5a184 _PyType_Lookup + 1343  44  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    45  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff92df5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416     46  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   47  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff958c8 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 929   48  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff924d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079     49  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   50  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    51  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    52  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff93395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856     53  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   54  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff958c8 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 929   55  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff924d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079     56  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   57  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    58  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    59  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff93395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856     60  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   61  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff958c8 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 929   62  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff924d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079     63  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   64  Python
>
>   0x000000010ff8ea24 PyEval_EvalCode + 54   65  Python
>
>   0x000000010ffadc2c PyParser_ASTFromFile + 306     66  Python
>
>   0x000000010ffadcd3 PyRun_FileExFlags + 137    67  Python
>
>   0x000000010ffad821 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718  68  Python
>
>   0x000000010ffbe363 Py_Main + 2995     69  libdyld.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff89e375fd start + 1  70  ???
>
>   0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2 ) 2014-10-16 15:15:18.367 Python[34300:d07]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan
>   nan]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fba325c __exceptionPreprocess + 172  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff86dc3e75 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff8fba310c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204     3   QuartzCore 
>   0x00007fff84cc425e _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 158   4
>   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff84cc41b7 -[CALayer
>   setPosition:] + 44    5   QuartzCore
>
>   0x00007fff84cc5e97 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 858     6   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8e5e837e -[_NSFullScreenTransitionOverlayWindow
>   positionLayers] + 1790    7   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8e5e8e61 -[_NSFullScreenTransitionOverlayWindow
>   startEnterFullScreenAnimationWithDuration:completionHandler:] + 55    8 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e5ead76
>   -[_NSFullScreenTransition _startFullScreenTransitionForCGWindow:targetFrame:duration:completionHandler:]
>   + 193     9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e5ecca6 __89-[_NSFullScreenTransition _performEnterFullScreenModeAnimating:activating:customWindows:]_block_invoke361
>   + 1430    10  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff84eafca2 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 47   11  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff84eafc2e _xpc_connection_call_reply + 36  12 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff869ab2ad
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff869b2f03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333  14 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fb0a679
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fac5954 __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 1636    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8fac50b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309   17  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff85ab9a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226    18  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff85ab97b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479   19  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff85ab95bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   65    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8dd293de
>   _DPSNextEvent + 1434  21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8dd28a2b -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122    22  SDL
>   0x000000011023243c SDL_SoftStretch + 7888     23  SDL
>   0x0000000110211efd SDL_PumpEvents + 38    24  SDL
>   0x00000001102120dd SDL_EventState + 200   25  SDL
>   0x00000001102303f6 SDL_JoystickEventState + 82    26  joystick.so
>   0x000000011040313d joy_autoinit + 42  27  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    28  Python
>   0x000000010ff9501f PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93     29  base.so
>   0x0000000110207c47 init + 279     30  Python
>   0x000000010ff921ef PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12338     31  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   32  Python
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    33  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    34  Python
>   0x000000010ff239a7 PyMethod_New + 1200    35  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    36  Python
>   0x000000010ff92df5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416     37  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   38  Python
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    39  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    40  Python
>   0x000000010ff239a7 PyMethod_New + 1200    41  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    42  Python
>   0x000000010ff5e6ce _PyObject_SlotCompare + 5565   43  Python
>   0x000000010ff5a184 _PyType_Lookup + 1343  44  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    45  Python
>   0x000000010ff92df5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416     46  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   47  Python
>   0x000000010ff958c8 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 929   48  Python
>   0x000000010ff924d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079     49  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   50  Python
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    51  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    52  Python
>   0x000000010ff93395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856     53  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   54  Python
>   0x000000010ff958c8 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 929   55  Python
>   0x000000010ff924d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079     56  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   57  Python
>   0x000000010ff36796 PyFunction_SetClosure + 809    58  Python
>   0x000000010ff18f72 PyObject_Call + 101    59  Python
>   0x000000010ff93395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856     60  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   61  Python
>   0x000000010ff958c8 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 929   62  Python
>   0x000000010ff924d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079     63  Python
>   0x000000010ff8f093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641   64  Python
>   0x000000010ff8ea24 PyEval_EvalCode + 54   65  Python
>   0x000000010ffadc2c PyParser_ASTFromFile + 306     66  Python
>   0x000000010ffadcd3 PyRun_FileExFlags + 137    67  Python
>   0x000000010ffad821 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718  68  Python
>   0x000000010ffbe363 Py_Main + 2995     69  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff89e375fd start + 1  70  ???
>   0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException
>
> Process finished with exit code 13

Comment: you are loading both `SDL1` and `SDL2`; you dont want to do that.

Comment: Yeah. I know. I was hoping someone whose ability to nerd outpaces my own (easy enough to do) might drum up a hack or work-around of some sort. Alas.

Comment: the only "hacks" to get around this UB would require as much work as just updating to pygame2 and ditching SDL1, which is what you really need to do.

Comment: Yeah, I'm conceding that. All the sighs.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting some in-house nerds, who confirmed [Brad Allred's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2899280/brad-allred) comment to my question, the solution is: using PyGame and SDL2 at the same time will essentially always require more work than replacing PyGame with SDL2. Don't do it.

Leaving my question just in case it ever proves to help.